# Javascript: Open url in current tab

Tags: javascript, html

I feel a little bit like a noob, but : How can I open a link in the current tab? I don't want to use `open(link);` 
.

Comment: `location.href = link`.

Comment: It's only polite to accept an answer if you question has been answered correctly.

Comment: Yes, you r absolutly right. i didnt know about this feature yet, cause im new to stackoverflow. but u know everybody has to start somewhere :)

Comment: No problem, welcome to the community :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a link in the same tab using:

```
window.location = "http://google.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

With html you can do:

```
<a href="index.html" target="self">Link</a>
```